# Splitting but retaining delimiters

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on a function to split a string but retain its delimiters.

```
Function SplitButRetainDelims(ByVal text As String, ByVal delimiters As String) As String()

    Dim Arr() As String, currentDelim As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Len(delimiters)
        currentDelim = Mid$(delimiters, i, 1)
        Arr = Split(Replace(text, currentDelim, currentDelim & "~"), "~")
    Next

    SplitButRetainDelims = Arr

End Function
```

The problem is that the way I have it now,

```
Arr = Split(Replace(text, currentDelim, currentDelim & "~"), "~")
```

will overwrite Array each time with only the split from the current delimiter. So instead of keeping the progress that previous iterations made, it resets.

I've nearly gotten to an acceptable solution before, but it was too involved to offer much benefit.

Edit: example

```
SplitButRetainDelims("potato (onion/soup / Green BEANS", " ()/") 
= ("potato", " ", "(", "onion", "/", "soup", " ", "/", "Green", " ", "BEANS")
```

Comment: Please provide some test data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't do the split till after all the replace:

```
Function SplitButRetainDelims(ByVal text As String, ByVal delimiters As String) As String()

    Dim Arr() As String, currentDelim As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Len(delimiters)
        currentDelim = Mid$(delimiters, i, 1)
        text = Replace(text, currentDelim, "~" & currentDelim & "~")
    Next
    text = Replace(text, "~~", "~")
    Arr = Split(text, "~")
    SplitButRetainDelims = Arr

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good step in the right direction, is it also possible to force the delimiters into their own "cells"

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 then you need to wrap the deliminator with the split value.  See edit.

Comment: Thanks, Scott, you're my hero

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 see new edit, added a check to ensure only one break and not two when the delimiters follow one another.